# Not able to increase the parallelism in spark using scala futures. Number of tasks processing parquet files is not increasing more than 50

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to parallelize the number of parquet files in HDFS processed at a time using scala futures. I am trying to delete records from HDFS file and create a new file without deleted records. I wanted to process multiple files concurrently and adjust it based on `runAtATime` variable. Even though I set `runAtATime` at 500 only 50 files are getting processed at time. It is not increasing more than 50. I tried different spark configuration, but did not work.

Code snippet:

```
    val partitions_file_list = listAllFilesFolderInDir(spark, base_path, true, filePaths) 
    for(start_index <-0 to partitions_file_list.size by runAtATime) {
            val end_index = if( start_index + runAtATime >= partitions_file_list.size) partitions_file_list.size else start_index + runAtATime
            val files_list = partitions_file_list.slice(start_index,end_index).map(_.toString)
            for(inner_index <-0 to files_list.length-1) {
                    var args: Array[String] = null
                    args = Array(
                        "file_name", files_list(inner_index),
                    )
                    argsList = args :: argsList
                }

    def runner(qcArgsThread: Array[String]) = Future {
        val kvpairs = qcArgsThread.grouped(2).collect { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
        val file_name = kvpairs("file_name")
        var Input_table_file = s"parquet.`${file_name}`"
        val fileHash = md5Hash(file_name.toString)

        Join_Query = Join_Query.replace("<Input_table_file>", Input_table_file)
        var df_joined = spark.sql(Join_Query)

        var curated_df = df_joined.filter(col(s"${Customer_ID}").isNotNull && (col(s"reference_${LKP_CUSTOMER_ID}").isNull))
        var deleted_df = df_joined.filter(col(s"${Customer_ID}").isNotNull && (col(s"reference_${LKP_CUSTOMER_ID}").isNotNull))
        val delete_count : Double = deleted_df.count()
        val folder_name = (file_name splitAt (file_name lastIndexOf "/") + 1)._1
        if (delete_count > 0) {
            var folder_name_temp = folder_name.replace(base_path, base_path + s"_temp/file$fileHash")
            curated_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(folder_name_temp)
            var filePaths_temp = new ListBuffer[Path]()
            val file_list_temp = listAllFilesFolderInDir(spark, folder_name_temp, true, filePaths_temp)
            for (file_temp <- file_list_temp){
                val files_list_target = file_temp.toString.replace(base_path + s"_temp/file$fileHash",base_path)
                renameHDFSFile(spark,file_temp.toString,files_list_target)}}

    val futures = argsList map (i => runner(i))
    val allFutures = Future.sequence(futures)

    val result =
        try {
            Await.result(allFutures, Duration.Inf)
        } catch {
            case e: Exception =>
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    System.exit(1)
            }
```

Spark configuration:

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
--conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=600
--driver-cores 2
--executor-memory 20g
--num-executors 70
--executor-cores 3
--conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=snappy
--deploy-mode cluster
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1
--driver-memory 30G
--conf spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=4g
--conf spark.default.parallelism=1
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4G
--conf spark.sql.hive.manageFilesourcePartitions=False
--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2046m
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
```

Kindly assist me how to process more than 50 parquet file parallelly.

Spark version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to either be incomplete or have syntax errors. The `{` sign in your first `for` loop (line 2) has no corresponding `}` sign. Neither does the `{` sign on the `def runner(...` line. Could you please edit your post to correct/complete the code you've shared?

Comment: I have copied only part of code. There are no syntax errors. I am able to compile and run successfully. I went through the configuration file. Settings is set as `yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count` as 50 and `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count` as 50. I think they might have an impact

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to increase yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count and yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count to at least the number of executors, if not to 500 since that's the number of files you're attempting to process at once, as you've noticed already.

You'll probably also want to increase spark.default.parallelism to at least the number of executors, or better yet don't set it because it should default to the total number of cores across all executors. Setting it to 1 could cause performance issues with your Join query.

Comment: Can you please explain these parameters in detail - yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count and yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count. I am bit confused of their functionality.

Comment: Basically, Yarn is the cluster manager, so by setting those to a low limit, you're setting the maximum number of threads allowed to run at once on the cluster in parallel.